How host.docker.internal works on Windows
I just want to understand why on Windows the IP of host.docker.internal is not the IP of the host, neither 172.17.0.1.
How all of this works on Docker?
I've already read the documentation but couldn't understand how this all works out.
The connection flows like that: container > 172.17.0.1 > host.docker.internal > host ?
If yes, why it doesn't connects directly to the host instead of going through host.docker.internal?

What is your Docker host networking configuration? Docker Desktop uses the hosts virtual networking config.

Why are you expecting 172.17.0.1 to be used?

@music2myear I use the default switch on Hyper-V and all the containers are on the default mode (bridge)

@Ramhound because it's the default gateway of the containers on a bridge Docker network. If you run a container with no additional configuration you can check that it has an IP of 172.17.0.2 and there's already a 172.17.0.1 that is the default gateway

Where are you seeing this "host.docker.internal" though?

Note that on Windows, Docker (Desktop) pretty much always runs the engine and the containers in a (Linux) VM. (Even if you use WSL instead of Hyper-V, WSL itself is pretty much a VM as well.) I don't know if you can change it by any means, but at least by default, the VM would be connected to a separate virtual network (which Windows is also connected to and serves as the default gateway of the VM). AFAIK, host.docker.internal is set to the default gateway address in the VM, which means it IS an IP of the Windows host, while 172.17.0.1 is an IP of the VM, configured on docker0.

By separate virtual network I mean like the VM is connected to an "internal switch" (with NAT), but not bridged to a physical network Windows is connected to (such as your home LAN) with an "external switch". The address host.docker.internal is set/resolved to is the IP configured on that "internal switch" (which may or may not be "hidden"), while it's not the IP configured on any of the physical NICs, it's still an IP of the Windows host.

@TomYan what I don't get is: 1) If the flow it goes. Like, in most of the linux distros cases, if you use 172.17.0.1 it will communicate with the host machine, but why if it isn't the host's IP on the real network?  2) So in the Windows case the 172.17.0.1 is the docker0 IP like you said, it would be like a router's IP on a network or like a switch device IP (I know they don't have on a real network)? 3) How can the host.docker.internal IP resolves to the host's IP if it's not on my ipconfig on Windows or any other device on the host's network? 4) What would be the package flow Win?

@Kobra but why if it isn't the host's IP on the real network? I don't get what you mean by this. Hopefully my answer got it covered.

@TomYan yes it covered! What I was asking is just kinda dumb. I was asking why the host.docker.internal didn't have the IP of the NIC on the local network, but you answered it by saying it have the IP of the Internal Switch that is on the same netns of the NIC

Let me illustrate with diagrams the difference between the case of having the docker engine running on a Linux host directly and and the case of Docker Desktop (which is more or less the only case in Windows, because Windows is not Linux):

Note that the diagrams in this answer is illustrating the "network structures". That's why you are seeing that the containers are "outside" the Linux host. At least for a Linux host, you can pretty much reach it with an IP configured on any of its interfaces. Therefore, essentially you can reach the docker host with either the IP configurd on eth0, docker0, some br-xxx (non-default docker bridges) or any other that exists in its the "default" network namespace (netns). Network-wise a different netns is pretty much like a different host, which is why docker containers, which each have their own netns, are like separate hosts in "virtual" LANs (in the sense of "emulated"; anyway, not "VLAN"). The docker bridges are like virtual switches, with one of their ports connected to the host, and the others connected to the containers. So the docker host is like connected to multiple LANs (broadcast domains), and it serves as a router for the containers. (You can more or less see the eth0 as the "WAN interface" from the POV of the containters.)

When it comes to the Docker Desktop case, it's really just like nesting the "bare metal" Linux case into a VM. A VM is obviously just like a "separate host" as a container does, and at least by default, it is also connected to a "internal switch", which is like a docker bridge to the containers, and because of that, you would be able to reach the Windows host with the IP configured on that switch (you can also see it as a virtual NIC connected to a port of that switch).
Note that the switch is not really "a part of the docker stuff", but just a part of WSL / Hyper-V. The private IP/subnet used is not chosen by docker either.


How can the host.docker.internal IP resolves to the host's IP if it's not on my ipconfig on Windows or any other device on the host's network?


I haven't really looked at the code of docker (actually it might not even be open since Docker Desktop consists of blobs, I think), but I believe that the DNS "answers" for host.docker.internal is derived from gateway address in the default route (i.e. default gateway) of the VM. (To be frank, I haven't really even checked on Windows. I only "fact checked" by running Docker Desktop on Linux, which runs KVM with qemu.) The default gateway is advertised to the VM by the hypervisor through DHCP.
I don't really have the exact reason for why Microsoft decided to "hide" some of the internal switches (well, the "default" / "special" ones), but IIRC, the fact that they are hidden does not necessarily mean that you can't reach the Windows host with the IP configured on those switches.
I don't exactly know whether you can reach a Windows host from a network with IP that is configured on an adapter that is NOT attached to the network either (like you can reach a Linux host).


What would be the package flow Win?


Either way, adapters are not separate hosts, there's no such thing as "flow" from adapter to another adapter when you are talking the same destination host. When traffics have arrived at a host via an interface, they have arrived. They would only get through another (or the same) interface if their "ultimate" destination is not the host, but some other host, in which case L3/IP forwarding would occur (basically, that means the host works as a gateway/router and the traffics goes from one network to another network; occasionally, the same one). For example, if you containers try to reach Google, or a device in your home LAN.



So in the Windows case the 172.17.0.1 is the docker0 IP like you said, it would be like a router's IP on a network or like a switch device IP (I know they don't have on a real network)?


I don't really get the question, but yes (I suppose?), 172.17.0.1 is a "router's IP", in the sense that the Linux host (that runs the containers, regardless of whether it is a VM) is a router / (default) gateway for the containers. Note though you can have more than one docker bridge, and 172.17.0.1 is just the usual address configured on the default one (docker0). Containers would really have their default gateway set to the IP address configured on the docker bridge they are connected to.

It might be worth mentioning that host.docker.internal is "Docker Desktop specific", i.e., by default / OOTB you won't get any answer for it in the "bare metal" case, although it seems that some "infrastructure" has been added to allow you to "mimic" something similar. (I haven't really checked whether the "infrastructure" would give the IP configured on a respective docker bridge or the default gateway on the Linux host.)
Also, gateway.docker.internal that is (also) mentioned here gives the same answer as host.docker.internal does (at least when Docker Desktop runs on Linux). I am still not sure if under any circumstances they could give different answers though.

Much thanks mate! Thanks very much for the effort of explaining this in so nice way
